# how to find out odoo db link from odoo URL. "thiscotime-thisco-erp-testing-3132300.dev" does not exist

Tags: odoo

what is the db link of odoo from my instance url https://thiscotime-thisco-erp-odoo-dev-3132464.dev.odoo.com/web#cids=1&home=.

i use odoo sh. i also follow this link https://www.odoo.com/documentation/14.0/developer/misc/api/odoo.html . to get odoo db url.

error :conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)\npsycopg2.OperationalError: FATAL:  database "thiscotime-thisco-erp-testing-3132300.dev" does not exis

Answer (score 1):

[image]

"thiscotime-thisco-erp-odoo-dev-3132464" inside () is your db name

Comment: db = "thiscotime-thisco-erp-testing-3132300", i have tried  your suggestion, now the error is xmlrpc.client.Fault: <Fault 3: 'Access Denied'>.  . but the user and password can login from web  https://thiscotime-thisco-erp-odoo-dev-3132464.dev.odoo.com/web#cids=1&home=

Comment: [I used this code it working fine](https://pastebin.com/eW5js7gK)